# Serve compiled javascript and css files from rails app for use in external site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

How can I make some asset files (.js and .css) from my rails app available to another site?

Example:

```
// allow this to be added to some external website
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myrailsapp.com/external/mystyle.css">
<script src="https://myrailsapp.com/external/myscript.js"></script>
```

The js and css files should be compiled by the standard asset pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rails 5 add the desired assets to be precompiled in `config/initializers/assets.rb`

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( external/myscript.js external/mystyle.css )`

This will generate a precompiled version of your assets on each deploy.

**With digest (default rails behavior, recommended)**

There is a problem with appended digest though. Precompiled assets will be named something like

`mystyle-36050fdf64ed881b967d4216084ed3072da6369f1b4dcf783ea28435f6db0091.css`

You can alter your deployment setup to run a rake task that will remove the digest from the asset's filename. For example https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/lib/tasks/ckeditor.rake

Let's say you are using capistrano to deploy your application. You have to add something like this to `config/deploy.rb`

```
namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, 'your_rake_task_namespace:task_name'
end
```

**Without digest (simpler but hurts cache invalidation)**

If you don't want to add complexity to your deploy setup just disable assets fingerprinting. Do it globaly by adding `config.assets.digest = false` in `config/application.rb` or for a single environment `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: I hesitate to add the extra complexity of removing the digest. I'd prefer dynamic creation with a fixed route unless performance turns out to be prohibitive.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can disable the digest by adding `config.assets.digest = false`  to `config/application.rb`

Comment: @de. it does, the only difference is that in rails 4 there is no `config/initilizers/assets.rb` so you have to add `config.assets.precompile += ['your-asset.js']` to `config/application.rb`

Comment: You already helped me a lot, I have the logical follow-up question about cache-control: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59887924/921573 Would you share some more insights?